# Why doesn't TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(container, sharedAxis) accept sharedAxis? [Android]

Tags: android, material-components-android

According to [Material Motion Development Guide for Android](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/motion#shared-axis), you can have views automatically animate through their shared axis by setting up the following

```
// Set up a new MaterialSharedAxis in the specified axis and direction.
val sharedAxis = MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Y, true)

// Begin watching for changes in the View hierarchy.
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(container, sharedAxis)

// Make any changes to the hierarchy to be animated by the shared axis transition.
outgoingView.visibility = View.GONE
incomingView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

However, when I call `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(container, sharedAxis)`, `beginDelayedTransition()` only accepts `(ViewGroup sceneRoot)` or `(ViewGroup sceneRoot, Transition transition)` as arguments and not `(ViewGroup sceneRoot, MaterialSharedAxis)` as stated in Material.io's guide. Why is that so?

Here are my Gradle dependencies

build.gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72"

    // Constraint Layout
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"

    // Core
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.0"

    // Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-rc01"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
}
```

build.gradle (project)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$version_kotlin"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that Android Studio automatically imported import `android.transition.TransitionManager` instead of the import `androidx.transition.TransitionManager`.